# Select multiple tables in Laravel Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 9. I have defined the relationships in the appropriate models.

1st Model - Client (all client-related information) Primary Key (ID)

```
class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function appointments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Appointment::class, 'client_id');
    }

    public function vehicles()

    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class, 'client_id');
    }
}
```

2nd Model - Appointments (appointment info only) Foreign Key (client_id)

```
class Appointment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
    }
 
}
```

3rd Model - Vehicles (vehicle info only) Foreign key (client_id)

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
    }
   
}
```

I'm trying to select all from the three tables where IDs match using a where clause.

Here's my eloquent query code

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $clients = Client::with(['appointments', 'vehicles'])
        ->where('default_location', 'MM Alencar')
        ->get()
        ->dd();

        // return view('dashboard', ['clients' => $clients]);
    }
}
```

The DD returns two client models.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => App\Models\Client {#1253 ▶}
  1 => App\Models\Client {#1254 ▶}
]
```

Both models are identical. I don't see any appointment or vehicle data attached. Sorry for the edit; I don't think I was clear enough on the first post. I need to be able to loop through the query as it will return anyone whose appointment type = 'test'

Comment: You made a typo ```return view('dashboard', [ 'clients' => $client ]);``` should be
```return view('dashboard', [ 'clients' => $clients ]);```

Comment: TIP : you can put many relationship with one `with()`. ex. `with(['appointments','vehicles'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo problem on your issue because you have written with `appointments`, and on view, you are trying to return `$client->appointment` (without 's').

Besides this, also confirm what the relationship names on the model is it `appointment` or `appointments`, if it is `appointments` and holds the relation `one to many` on that case, `$client->appointments->type` will also return error because, here `appointments` will return collections, on that case you need to map the `$client->appointments` and fetch type of each collection

Update:

After your update on the question, I can confirm that it has one to many relationships. So to get an appointment with a particular client you could do as:

```
foreach($clients as $k => $v){
  $v->appointments->dd(); //here you will get the appointments in array/collection. then you have to loop it in foreach / map/ pluck according to your needs.

}
```

Comment: Saroj, Please see the updated post.

Comment: @theothernick my pleasure, you can mention me if you ever need help on any other questions on Stack Overflow.